# Ionic 3 Firebase Phone Authentication not working on real device

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I am working on an Ionic 3 Firebase Phone Authentication demo app. It is running well on browser localhost and also sends the OTP message to the given phone number. But when I deployed same app on real android device it is not working to get OTP message.

What I am missing... I am really stuck here...

Comment: Any console errors on the real device?

Comment: The programs executed without error on browser and also sends the OTP message to given phone number.. but not sends OTP from android device.. What I am missing?.. in Ionic or Firebase Or Website?

Comment: You need to debug on the device and see the console error there. https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/developer-tips/

Comment: I will check Sir...